# Can I make USB drive bootable and install multiple OSes from it?

Tags: usb, boot, installation, multi-boot, usb-flash-drive

Is it possible to have USB drive bootable and place multiple ISOs like

- Windows 7.iso
- WindowXP.iso
- Ubuntu.iso
- RHEL.iso

so that I can choose which OS to install?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use **[MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/)** (Shareware, $30), it features a **Multi-Boot Image Editor**.

[image]

And here's a **[tutorial](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-create-multi-os-cd-3.htm)**.

Comment: Thanks for that great tutorial. One thing more, I have 32GB USB . I also want to use that for installing OS and for general purpose use.
Is it possible that once i make the bootable image then make some files or portion Read only or hide them so that they can't be seen

Comment: @Mirage - i haven't tried to create a multi-boot OS disk, but have a look at UnetBootin. and for your next question: seen from where? there's always a way to view files even if they're hidden in windows.

Comment: That looks interesting, though 32Gb would be of limited use if you actually install programs

Comment: @Ivo - if you can make a bootable pocket HDD from that ISO, i think you get 1 TB now :)

Answer (score 12):

Free alternative:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/boot-multiple-iso-from-usb-multiboot-usb/

From the site:

> How to Boot Multiple ISO Files from
>   USB
>
> 1. Download and run MultiBootISOs.exe following the
>      onscreen instructions
> 2. Download some ISO Files (listed above) and place them on your Flash
>      Drive
> 3. Restart your PC setting it to boot from the USB device
> 4. Select the ISO you want to Boot from the Menu and enjoy!
>
> That's all there is to it. You should
>   now be booting your favorite ISO files
>   from your Multi-Boot USB device!

Limitations: As far as I can see you can only do this for the O.S's on their list:

> ```
> * Run MemTest86+ ISO from USB (Get ISO from Zip)
> * Boot Linux Mint 8 ISO from USB
> * Boot Ubuntu 9.10 ISO from USB
> * Boot Xubuntu 9.10 ISO from USB
> * Boot Kubuntu 9.10 ISO from USB
> * Boot Ubuntu 9.10 Netbook Remix from USB
> * Boot Ubuntu 9.10 Rescue Remix from USB
> * Boot Ubuntu 9.10 Server Install ISO from USB
> * Boot Parted Magic 4.8 ISO from USB (get ISO from Zip)
> * Boot DSL 4.4.10 initrd ISO from USB
> * Boot Ultimate Boot 4.11 CD (UBCD) ISO from USB
> * Boot SliTaz Linux 2.0 ISO from USB
> * Boot OphCrack XP ISO from USB
> * Boot OphCrack Vista ISO from USB
> * Boot Offline NT Password + Reg Editor from USB (get ISO from Zip)
> * Boot RIPLinux 9.3 ISO from USB
> * Boot Ylmf OS (Windows Like OS) ISO from USB
> * Boot DBAN 1.0.7 (Hard Drive Nuker) ISO from USB
> * Boot xPUD (Simple NetBook Distro) ISO from USB
> * Run FreeDOS (Balder Image) from USB (put balder10.img on USB)
> * Boot boot.kernel.org (BKO) gpxe.lkrn from USB (put gpxe.lkrn on
> ```
>
> USB)

And if you don't like the above solution (I don't), you can try this one:

http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=18846

It's based on "Syslinux"

Comment: note that most linux LiveCDs include an option to install the OS once booted from the iso-on-flash-drive.